# PWA not working on deployment in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to implement PWA in one of my projects (ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC). I have added the following on top of my cshtml file.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Have also added the following in my project file.

```
<PackageReference Include="WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA" Version="1.0.65" />
```

It works fine in my local but not on deployment. The manifest file was added to the `wwwroot` folder.

I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: i think the problem is the webserver (is it an IIS?) is not serving the manifest ..can you check if the manifest is 404 ?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 has already reached End Of Life and that package hasn't been updated since 2020. The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6. I don't remember if that package was needed at all in 3.1 or if it was for older projects. It's definitely not needed in supported ASP.NET Core versions

Comment: Check the [Single Page Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0) documentation for ASP.NET Core support for SPAs, examples and templates for specific frameworks like React, Angular, Vue.

Comment: BTW you didn't post the full error, the manifest or your service worker script. The part of the error you posted complains that the *manifest itself* is invalid. A line above this seems to say the *service worker* was served as HTML, not JavaScript.

Comment: Please share more details of your errors in order to get more insight, and provide a way to reproduce your issue.